# vim crashes with AutoComplPop plugin

Tags: ruby, vim

I use vim to edit the ruby files, but it crashes when I type ".".
I've found that it is caused by the AutoComplPop plugin.
What I should do?

Comment: 1. Get rid of it, 2. Find another auto completion plugin.

Comment: What is the backtrace? Without any information I can only guess. Statisctically I'd say missing or incompatible Python 3 libs

Comment: @sehe: AutoComplPop doesn't use Python, it's pure Vimscript; but otherwise, a good guess.

Comment: Agree with @romainl - AutoComplPop hasn't been updated since 2009. I switched to NeoComplCache (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2620) a few months ago and like it better.

Comment: Thanks，I have tried the NeoComplCache ,but it also crashed.the module name of this issue is msvcrt-ruby191.dll.

Answer (score 5):

I found a way to prevent the vim crashing using autocomplpop and filetype=ruby.

put the follow line in your **.vimrc**

```
let g:acp_behaviorRubyOmniMethodLength = -1
```

this will prevent autocomplpop trigger when you type the "." (period)

It isn't a fix. (I'm not a vim plugin programmer)

good luck!

Comment: Fell on the exact same situation. Except that it also breaks on other autocompletion too. Not only `.`. *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

Report this to the author of AutoComplPop; you'll find his address at `:help acp-author`. State the exact Vim version (`:version` output), plugin version, and OS / environment, and exact steps to reproduce.

If you're interested, you could delve into the source code of the plugin and try to come up with a minimal fragment that shows the crash. If this crash still occurs in the latest development snapshot of Vim, it should be reported to the vim_dev mailing list. But usually the plugin author is best equipped (and motivated) to do this for you.